# How to do add/subtract document-term matrices in quanteda?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, quanteda

Consider this simple example

```
dfm1 <- tibble(text = c('hello world',
                         'hello quanteda')) %>% 
  corpus() %>% tokens() %>% dfm()
> dfm1
Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 3 features (33.3% sparse).
2 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
       features
docs    hello world quanteda
  text1     1     1        0
  text2     1     0        1
```

and

```
dfm2 <- tibble(text = c('hello world',
                        'good nigth quanteda')) %>% 
  corpus() %>% tokens() %>% dfm()
Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 5 features (50.0% sparse).
2 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
       features
docs    hello world good nigth quanteda
  text1     1     1    0     0        0
  text2     0     0    1     1        1
```

As you can see, we have the same text identifiers in the two `dfms`: `text1` and `text2`.

I would like to "subtract" `dfm2` to `dfm1` so that each entry in `dfm1` is subtracted to its (possibly) matching entry in `dfm2` (same text, same word)

So for instance, in `text1`, `hello` occur 1 time and in `text2` it also occurs 1 time. So the output should have 0  for that entry (that is: 1-1). Of course, entries that are not in both `dfms` should be kept unchanged.

How can I do that in quanteda?

Comment: You want to subtract the counts for matching features in `dfm1` _from_ `dfm2`? Or `dfm2` from `dfm1`?

Comment: the order does not really matter. I want to add or subtract matching features across dfms. does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the feature set of a dfm to that of another dfm using `dfm_match()`.  I've also tidied up your code since for this short example, some of your pipeline could be simplified.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.4.3
## Parallel computing: 2 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

dfm1 <- dfm(c("hello world", "hello quanteda"))
dfm2 <- dfm(c("hello world", "good night quanteda"))

as.dfm(dfm1 - dfm_match(dfm2, features = featnames(dfm1)))
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 3 features (33.3% sparse).
## 2 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##        features
## docs    hello world quanteda
##   text1     0     0        0
##   text2     1     0        0
```

The `as.dfm()` comes from the fact that the `+` operator is defined for the parent sparse **Matrix** class and not specifically for a **quanteda** dfm, so it drops the dfm's class and turns it into a `dgCMatrix`.  Coercing it back into a dfm using `as.dfm()` solves that but it will drop the original attributes of the dfm objects such as docvars.

Comment: actually I now realize something even more interesting. One could just use the union of features (features(dfm1) UNION feaures(dfm2)) in the `features` argument so that the output dfmcontains all the words used in the dfms (not only the ones in common).

Comment: To combine the features from two dfms, you could also use `dfm_compress(cbind(dfm1, dfm2), margin = "features")`.